# VS code не подтягивает методы скачанных библиотек Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

[image: Скрин проблемы]

Я скачал библиотеки react-redux, react-router-dom и т.д, но когда я пытаюсь использовать методы или функции или хуки из этих библиотек они не подсвечиваются в подсказках до того момента пока я их сам не впишу вручную, после этого они мне станут появляться в подсказках. И то на определенный срок, а потом как будто память стирается и все по новой начинай прописывать. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Ну вы делаете не правильно, если вы импортируете так реакт, то должны обращаться как `React.use`...

Comment: Библиотека React здесь не играет роль. Я скачал и добавил в проект библиотеку "react-router-dom", и не только эту, но возьмем к примеру ёё. И теперь, когда я прописываю useParams() мне должно показать возможность импортнуть этот хук из библиотеки "react-router-dom", но вместо этого пустота. Хотя если я ручками пропишу импорт всё работает. Подчеркну, useParams к библиотеке React не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: Понял о чем вы, странно тогда. Вы пробовали в `.ts/tsx` файлах?

Comment: @Edward у вас в проекте есть jsconfig файл?

Comment: В .ts/tsx аналогичная ситуация. В дереве проектов, кроме моих папок и файлов есть только package.json/package-lock.json, никаких jsconfig не создается. На удивление, я выключил расширение auto import и пока сегодня сбоев не было. Возможно совпадение, ещё понаблюдаю.

Comment: Таки нет, проблема осталась.

Comment: А еще заметил, когда использую(хочу импортировать) метод из другого файла (он закрыт) среда не видит, но когда файл открыт в соседнем окне среда разработки увидит все его доступные для импорта методы. Заметил подобную проблему и у напарника. Хоть бери да переустанавливай vs code, и то не факт что поможет...